# Windows credential provider not shown in 21H1

Tags: windows, windows-10, provider, windows-10-v21h1

I am developing a custom credential provider since the beginning of 2021

I took the reference from Credential Provider V2 from https://github.com/DavidWeiss2/windows-Credential-Provider-library

So far it works fine for Windows 10 Home version 20H2, version 2004

However Today I install new Windows OS on virtual machine for testing, and it is installed based on Windows 10 version 21H2

After I read the release notes https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/status-windows-10-21h1 I think I don't find any word that specify logonUI or something that related to windows credential provider

Does anyone know how to fix this problem, or at least explain why this is happening?

---

*ex. Windows 10 Home version 20H2, version 2004*

[image: Windows 10 Home version 20H2, version 2004 - Screenshot]

*ex. Windows 10 version 21H2. Picture taken from Laptop not VM*

[image: Windows 10 version 21H2 - Screenshot]

**---------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------**

Due to my bad English and unclear Image, I think I did not explain the problem correctly

Here I attach the Latest picture of my Laptop using PrintScreen funtion. So there are **no Arrow Anywhere**

[image: Current condition of Windows logon]

Comment: Hit the arrow.  It appears the list is simply suppressed

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, which arrow? the picture below is because I take the screenshot and send it using Line messenger on PC. That arrow is shown when you open a picture using Line messenger on PC. It has nothing to do with the credential provider

Comment: The arrow on the left side of the screen.  If the 21H1 VM isn’t a clone of the first VM then you probably have a group policy configured on the original VM and not configured on the 21H1 VM

Comment: @Ramhound I am sorry if my picture is confusing, so I add the latest picture below. Just to make sure that **There are now arrow** over there ._.

Comment: What is the configuration status of **Interactive logon: Do not display last user name**, **Interactive logon: Don’t display username at sign-in**, and **Enumerate local users on domain-joined computers**

Comment: Interactive logon: Do not display last user name --> Disabled | Interactive logon: Do not display last user name--> Not-Defined | Not Configured

Comment: What about the last one? This is information that should be in the question

Comment: Oh I am sorry, that I did not reply it well.  Interactive logon: Do not display last user name --> Disabled | Interactive logon: Do not display last user name--> Not-Defined | Enumerate local users on domain-joined computers --> Not Configured

Comment: Configure the later policies as Disabled and reboot the system.  In order to make any difference the machine must have at least 2 accounts that are enabled.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help so far. Secondly, whether I did not explain well, or you misunderstood my goal, I still cant reach my goal yet. If I tried to add new user, yes there are two users there. But the custom credential that I developed still not showing. [This is after I add new user](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gN07qZVouoWBkTjJUKWpOg-X4utZHTT3/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Then something most definitely did change, sounds more like a Stack Overflow question at this point.  I took your question as you were unable to get the list of users to be shown, that was handled by the group policy, even your custom credential would have needed a user linked to it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out we need the Microsoft Visual Studio C++ redistribute to work.

Thanks to [swiversecure](https://kb.swivelsecure.com/w/index.php/Windows_Credential_Provider)

> Important: the Credential Provider requires Microsoft Visual Studio C++ redistributable to work. Recent operating systems already include this, but it will need to be installed on older operating systems if it has not already been installed. You can retrieve it from here. If you have already installed the credential provider, it is not necessary to uninstall it before installing the redistributable.

I don't know what is the reason why in version 21H1, that package is not included. Therefore, I have to download it first [using this link](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe). It is not necessary to restart the pc or reinstall the Credential provider, so I just lock my pc to see result. Then, my custom credential provider just showed up ._.